# Every regular language is decidable

Tags: math, theory, decidable

I am a trying to prove that every regular language is decidable.

So in order to prove that I am trying to show that I can move from  deterministic finite automaton (DFA) to a Turing decidable machine.

So I am not sure how to construct a Turing machine that simulates the original automate (DFA).

The states (in the automate and the Turing machine ) will be similar off course.. but I am not sure how to continue..

Thanks in advance. 
Shiran

Comment: You better ask that at [Math Site](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't this work : the input tape carries the word to be recognised followed by some letter # from outside the input alphabet. For each state q of the DFA, you have a Turing machine state q with transitions:

```
input letter -> tape operation,  next state, write symbol

c for each input letter -> move right, the state the DFA reaches from state q with letter c, write c
# -> STOP ACCEPT or STOP REJECT, depending on whether q is final in the DFA.
```